# Using switchClass as a polyfill for animations in IE8

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css, jquery-animate, frontend

http://jqueryui.com/switchClass/

I recently found `switchClass` under JqueryUI and used it on a project with great success (custom building the JQuery UI down to about 8k) - it helped me solve a problem of getting animations to work in a similar way I would when using CSS3 animations

ie. `addClass`, `removeClass`, with the added functionality of actually swapping the classes, and then animating between

I was wondering though, would there be a good way to use this as a polyfill, so only when required with modernizer

Been thinking about it for a couple of hours now, would be interested in other peoples suggestions

Comment: Well, you just have to check if css transitions are supported by the client: if they are, use toggleClass, otherwise use switchClass. There are a number of ways to detect CSS transitions support, a quick search here on SO should reveal some.

Comment: Also it should be easy to create a plugin that extends addClass, removeClass etc if you want the functionality built in.

Comment: that's what I was thinking - might write one - was just interested to see if anyone else had thought about this before I started

Comment: The only thing is I don't think you can read the parameters of the transition properties in the stylesheet if the browser doesn't support them, i.e. a possible plugin would not know which duration to apply for an animation in case css transitions aren't supported, unless explicitly passed.

Comment: There are several plugins out there that extend jQuery.animation to use css transitions when they are supported by the way, this is probably the most sane way to handle it. No idea if that'd work with switchClass out of the box, but it might if the method uses jQuery.animate internally.